# Calling custom loading method through a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

This question is a two-parter, I've looked about but have not been able to find a question like it, but perhaps I just didn't know specifically what to search for.

I have a container view which acts like a navigation for the user (with other options like saving) which sits at the top of most of my `UIViewController`s. So each view is accessible from every other view. The problem I have is that this can create loops in the `UINavigationController` which is not advised. My attempt at the moment is to remove all but the root `UIViewController` and then load the new view controller. This is no good, while it loads alright, my assets are fairly memory intensive so loading them from scratch or having multiple instances loaded at one time takes a bit too much memory. I am going to reduce the asset size asap to reduce memory pressure but I still think the way I am doing it is pretty horrible and inefficient so I want to know a more efficient way of managing the `UIViewController`s.

The other part of this question is about loading these `UIViewController`s. I have multiple ways to enter certain `UIViewController`s and they need slightly different configurations. I know I could load the `UIViewController` manually with a specific init method, or I could use an `NSNotification` to tell the class to do some extra initialisation stuff, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this, and if there isn't which option would be better?

Sorry for the wall of text, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: U can change the navigationviewcontroller.viewcontroller  with ur existing created view then add it again with new order also remove some view controller..

Answer (score 1):

For question one, it sounds like you should not be using a UINavigationController as the base for your container view controller. Instead you should be using your own custom container view controller.

If you want to check out an example of a custom container view controller, or to simply use a class that makes it a little easier to create one, you can check out my class CLFContainerViewController on GitHub: https://github.com/cflesner/CLFContainerViewController

It's not updated yet to use all of the new animation options that iOS 7 offers, so it's a little clunky to animate the transitions (although it gives you a lot of flexibility). It is fully compatible with iOS 7 though.

For question two, how you create them is entirely personal preference. You can create custom init methods, or you can just have properties that you set to configure the view controller. If you're using a custom container view controller, you will either need to initialize them with some flavor of init, or if you're using storyboards you can call instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifer: to get an instance of one.

Comment: Oh the container view controller is not a uinavigation controller, rather is an intermediary, like hitting a button in the navigation container bar calls a method which changes the current view controller. Sorry if that seemed a bit unclear.